# DB2 query with table name prefixed by database name not working with Entity Manager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, db2-400

i have my DB2 database (suppose ajaydb) and a table name employee.so i have written my query (`select * from ajaydb.employee`). to execute this query i am using entity Manager like:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("Here my query").getResultList();
```

Then i get error:`Invalid Object.`

But same is working fine if i use SessionFactory of Hibernate.like

```
session.createSQLQuery("my query").list();
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Actually ,we have multiple tables with join and  not done mapping in entities so written native sql query .Problem is not with Query type but its not taking databsename.tablename .

Comment: my apologies..actually its createNativeQuery syntax